# Extract a character after a particular string

Tags: c#, regex, regular-language

I want to extract a character after a particular string, example:

```
 Sentence: "Develop1 Tester2 BA3"
 String: Develop
 Expected result: "1"
```

I tried the Regex as following but still not get result as my expectation, please consult me, thank in advance.

```
RegEx: /[DEVELOP\d]\[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d*)?/
```

Comment: See [the solution](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Develop%28%5b%2b-%5d%3f%5cd*%5c.%3f%5cd%2b%29&i=Develop1+Tester2+BA3). The point is as in the linked post: `string` + `(pattern_you_need_to_extract)`. Or, `(?<=string)pattern_you_need_to_extract`

Comment: Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a regex for this.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var input = "Develop1 Tester2 BA3";
var search = "Develop";
if (input.StartsWith(search) && input.Length > search.Length) {
    var result = input[search.Length];

    Console.Write("Result: " + result);
}
```